# Updating 2 columns in 2 tables and joining multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I am having trouble updating multiple rows in multiple tables and joining multiple columns, i have to update the expiry date in the table called policy and also give a 10% discount the rate in table called rating_record to all staff who currently have an enforced policy.  I can give the 10% discount meeting all criteria but can not figure out how to update the Expiry date - please help!

The code I have up to now is I have to make all staff expiry dates be 31st jan using a 2nd update function. This needs to be done in Oracle 10g using SQL developer

```
    update rating_record
     set rate=(rate-(100/10)) where exists
    (select rating_record.rate from
    rating_record, coverage, policy, insured_by, client, person, staff
    where
   staff.pid = person.pid and
    client.pid = person.pid and
     client.cid = insured_by.cid and
    policy.pno = insured_by.pno and
     policy.pno = coverage.pno and 
    coverage.coid = rating_record.coid and
     policy.status = 'E');
```

Comment: FYI: rate-(100/10) takes 10 units off the rate, are you sure that you didn't want (rate * 0.9), or is rate a percentage value?

Answer (score 0):

You can only update values from one base table in an UPDATE statement.  You should instead create a procedure, and wrap two update statements (one per table to be updated) in a transaction.